# No funciona el botón de redirección al finalizar pago en mercadopago

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mercadopago

La pasarela de pago funciona bien, pero al finalizar el pago, no puedo hacer click en la flecha de volver al sitio del vendedor:
[image: pantalla final mercadopago]

El botón no hace nada, ni siquiera cambia el tipo de cursor.

Alguien ha tenido este problema y sabe cómo resolverlo? Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser un tema de configuración de Mercado Pago. La plataforma tiene una opción para indicar a donde redigirse después del pago.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]